# How to have Marquee kind of text in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, marquee

Is there any way to make the text in a Windows Form to scroll like the text in a marquee tag in HTML?

Comment: How does a presentation issue relate to a server side language?

Comment: i mean in vb.net forms ,can i make the form title moving???

like using timer or any thing that make that title move??

Comment: Is this WPF? WinForms? Something else?

Comment: There should be some automatic filter that prevents question with more than one consecutive question mark or exclamation mark from being posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer and a couple of variables to help you do so.  Something like this can be done...

```
'Class-level variables.
Private m_intMarqueeCounter As Integer = 1
Private m_bolMarqueeIncrementUp As Boolean = True

Private Sub YourMarqueeTimer_Tick()

   'You can decide what number is best for your app.
   If m_intMarqueeCounter = 10 Then

      m_bolMarqueeIncrementUp = False

   End If

   If m_intMarqueeCounter = 0 Then

      m_bolMarqueeIncrementUp = True

   End If

   Dim intX As Integer
   For intX = 0 to m_intMarqueeCounter

      frmYourForm.Text = " " & "Your Title"

   Next

   If m_bolMarqueeIncrementUp Then

      m_intMarqueeCounter += 1

   Else

      m_intMarqueeCounter -= 1

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: yes it works but i made some modification

i just but this code in the timer 

 Me.Text = " " & Me.Text & " "

Comment: @HAJJAJ - I think I don't understand what you mean by marquee.

Comment: no no , you give the right answer and you understand my Question

thank alot

Answer (score 1):

```
Const marqueeText As String = "The quick brown fox...   "
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim direction As Boolean = False 'true = left to right, false = right to left

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, _
                        e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If sb.Length = 0 Then sb.Append(marqueeText)
    If direction Then
        sb.Insert(0, sb(sb.Length - 1))
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1)
    Else
        sb.Append(sb(0))
        sb.Remove(0, 1)
    End If
    Me.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```