# using Label control to create looping marquee text in c# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been create Marquee text using Label control her is sample code

```
public partial class FrmMarqueeText : Form
{
    private int xPos = 0, YPos = 0;

    public FrmMarqueeText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrmMarqueeText_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            lblText.Text = "Hello this is marquee text";
            xPos = lblText.Location.X;
            YPos = lblText.Location.Y;
            timer1.Start();


    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (xPos == 0)
        {

            this.lblText.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Width, YPos);
            xPos = this.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblText.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xPos, YPos);
            xPos -= 2;
        }
    }
```

but  when the first time was finished, it didn't continues work .Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [marquee in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279136/marquee-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 3):

In timer1_Tick change

```
if (xPos == 0)
```

to

```
if (xPos <= 0)
```

Otherwise it won't work if `this.Width` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check if xPos <= 0. Because if xPos = 1 after xPos -= 2 your xPos will be equal to -1