# Why is this marquee code not working?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code in order to make a marquee label that scrolls from right to left.

```
    private int xPos = 651;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Width == xPos)
        {
            //repeat marquee
            xPos = 651;
            this.Label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(651, 334);
            xPos--;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xPos, 334);
            xPos--;
        }
    }
```

651 is the width of the form.

This code makes the label go from right to left, scroll off the form like it should, but doesn't restart at the right again.

Comment: Double negative in the title :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why not do marquee on the client-side using jquery or plain javascript?

Comment: @Dimitri, i think this is winform, i do too much webform :-p

Comment: Based on the function name (likely auto-generated by the designer) and the timer name (also likely generated just by dragging/dropping), I think it's safe to assume this is a winforms app.

Comment: @Brook webforms autogenerated names are exactly the same too. I just assumed it was webforms cause i do too much of webforms, just like Freduo

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you might have seen this : [using Label control to create looping marquee text in c# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323826/using-label-control-to-create-looping-marquee-text-in-c-sharp-winform)

Read the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `this.Width` is a positive value, therefore if you are doing repeated subtraction, you'll only ever achieve this value at the beginning.
Try  `if (xPos == 0)` instead

Answer (score 0):

that code for me make no sense to me

try this instead, tweak it like you want.

```
    private bool goLeft;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Label7.Width + Label7.Left >= this.Width)
        {
            goLeft = true;
        }
        else if (Label7.Left < 0)
        {
            goLeft = false;
        }

        Label7.Left += goLeft ? -10 : 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that it would be easier to just use the marquee from the client side, that wasn't what he was asking...

You are starting xPos at this.Width and decrementing it so, you need to reset xPos when it reaches 0 not this.Width. xPos is only equal to this.Width for the first iteration of each run.

```
private int xPos = this.Width;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (xPos == 0) { xPos = this.Width; }
    this.Label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xPos, 334);
    xPos--;
}
```

Comment: This works, however is there a way to tweak it so that it resets when the end of the label hits the left of the form, instead of the beginning?

Comment: Instead of the begining of what?